# Is my system disk damaged?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, startup

Recently I couldn't get my Mac (bought in April - 2009) to boot. The hard disk was quite full and honestly speaking I kept ignoring a number of warnings from OS X to 'free up some space'. I have been trying to fix it for the past month, and I have tried a lot based on information available on Internet.

The problems are:

1. The startup DVD I have takes me to Disk Utility but it fails to re-install Mac OS X.
2. The disk has errors and they are there even if I erased the disk completely.
3. `fsck -fy` is not able to repair the disk.
4. I created bootable USB for OS X El Capitan and I used it to boot the Mac: I get to the Apple logo and the progress bar filled up as well (after 1-2 hours)... but nothing happens after that.

Comment: Sounds like trying another HD might be the next step.

Comment: Are you saying that your Mac won't boot from the USB installer?  Have you tried [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.

Comment: Your 1st part of your description is a system disk full. This problem is solved with normal user method: archive old files and remove them. [return] The 2nd part of your description is a damaged disk. Follow the advice from @Allan, and if the test confirm the damage, change your disk.

Comment: I tried to perform AHT as suggested by Allan but I couldn't get it working. I have already erased the disk so I think I have to somehow install OS X to get AHT to work. I am also missing the 'recovery mode' on my Mac so only option I had was to use a USB. 
Thanks!

Comment: @Allan: Yes, if I use USB as installer, then I get to the apple logo and progress bar, but nothing happens after that. (See point number 4 in my question). Thanks.

Comment: Does booting up in Safe Mode help? I doubt it would. What about `Command-R` and `Shift-Command-R`?

Comment: @Brick: no I can't get to safe mode either. I only see 'Internet recovery' but that too fails. :-(